# Regex in java countries name

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need a regex for validation countries name. I tried the following regex:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*)+(?:[\\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

but allows the second or third name be lower character like:(United kingdom or United states).The correct value must be (United Kingdom or United States).How I modify my regex.

Comment: Replace `[a-zA-Z]+` with `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: What about country names that do have non-capitalized words, such as "Republic of Ireland"? Might as well not validate aside characters, whitespace, and minimal punctuation, due to alternative identifiers - that is, as long as you're not adhering to a specific standard...

Comment: Oh and can country names only be inserted in their English form? Otherwise consider `Österreich`.

Comment: What about "République Française"?

Comment: Only in Engish format else will be a disaster.it wasn't correct wot i was thinking [link](https://github.com/raramuridesign/mysql-country-list/blob/master/mysql-country-list.sql).I must let and lower character but the lower must not follow by upper

Comment: What about instead of validating if it was given correctly, why don't you just format it correctly regardless?

Comment: According to your logic, `Foo Bar` would be a valid country name. Only correct way to "validate" a country name, is to compare against a list of valid names.

Comment: @Andreas yes I have a list that will make match if the name is in the list  but i don't wont for the first step to input garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex (using .NET syntax but Java should be almost identical):

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

All names must start with a capital letter, so something like "United States" is valid but "United states" is not. The weakness, of course, is that "United States of America" isn't considered valid.

Also, the first letter can be the *only* capital letter in the word. This is to ban stuff like "UNited States." Of course, it also bans stuff like "USA".

One-letter country names are specifically *not* allowed (i.e. all country names must have at least two letters).

Answer (score 2):

The second part is incorrect. It allows mixed capital and small letters.
Take out the capitals to front and allow zero or more small letters.

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*)+(?:[\\s-][A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```